# Userform crashes excel on attempted load; listed as access error, I believe it's tied to linking labels to cells

Tags: excel, userform, vba

Will provide the problem signature at the bottom, as this is related, but isn't particularly the question.

---

**Background:**

I created a userform tied to a selection_change, which loads *provided* the VBA form builder for the form has been viewed.  All of the labels in the userform are tied to cells on a specific page of the workbook the userform is housed.

---

**Issue:**

That provisional in the background is important... if you just try to load the userform on the sheet, Excel crashes.

I believe the issue is that I caption the labels of the userform (Stb) before the userform has ever been loaded.  In using Stb.Show before the labeling, I get the basic form (I am unsure if the form can just be refreshed, which might be easier); if I try Unload Stb after Stb.Show, then I still have to action Stb before anything happens (force closing without having to look at it would be a workaround).

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to get the userform to either refresh all of the label captions once it has loaded?

Or, is there a way to force Unload the userform, after .Show, so I have an object to apply the captions?

Third thing, is there another approach which might be more preferable (*this is subjective; not intending to have a million options, but still want to ask*)?

---

**Code in question:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Cells(918, 6).Value = "No" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, t As Long
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    c = ActiveCell.Column
    i = 0
    Select Case r
        Case 25 To 44 '1
            i = 52
            t = 24
        Case 115 To 134 '2
            i = 142
            t = 114
        Case 205 To 224 '3
            i = 232
            t = 204
        Case 295 To 314 '4
            i = 322
            t = 294
        Case 385 To 404 '5
            i = 412
            t = 384
        Case 475 To 494 '6
            i = 502
            t = 474
        Case 565 To 584 '7
            i = 592
            t = 564
        Case 655 To 674 '8
            i = 682
            t = 654
        Case 745 To 764 '9
            i = 772
            t = 744
        Case 835 To 854 '10
            i = 862
            t = 834
    End Select
    If i = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(t + 1, 3), Cells(t + 20, 3))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With Sheets("Stability")
        Stb.Cond1.Caption = .Cells(r, c + 1)
        Stb.Cond2.Caption = .Cells(r, c + 1)
        Stb.TP01.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 3)
        Stb.TP02.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 4)
        Stb.TP03.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 5)
        Stb.TP04.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 6)
        Stb.TP05.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 7)
        Stb.TP06.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 8)
        Stb.TP07.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 9)
        Stb.TP08.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 10)
        Stb.TP09.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 11)
        Stb.TP10.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 12)
        Stb.TP11.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 13)
        Stb.TP12.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 14)
        Stb.TP13.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 15)
        Stb.TP14.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 16)
        Stb.TP15.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 17)
        Stb.TP16.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 18)
        Stb.TP17.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 19)
        Stb.TP18.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 20)
        Stb.TP19.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 21)
        Stb.TP20.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 22)
        Stb.TP21.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 23)
        Stb.TP22.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 24)
        Stb.TP23.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 25)
        Stb.TP24.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 26)
        Stb.TP25.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 27)
        Stb.TP26.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 28)
        Stb.TP27.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 29)
        Stb.TP28.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 30)
        Stb.TP29.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 31)
        Stb.TP01x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 3)
        Stb.TP02x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 4)
        Stb.TP03x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 5)
        Stb.TP04x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 6)
        Stb.TP05x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 7)
        Stb.TP06x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 8)
        Stb.TP07x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 9)
        Stb.TP08x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 10)
        Stb.TP09x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 11)
        Stb.TP10x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 12)
        Stb.TP11x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 13)
        Stb.TP12x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 14)
        Stb.TP13x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 15)
        Stb.TP14x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 16)
        Stb.TP15x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 17)
        Stb.TP16x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 18)
        Stb.TP17x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 19)
        Stb.TP18x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 20)
        Stb.TP19x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 21)
        Stb.TP20x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 22)
        Stb.TP21x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 23)
        Stb.TP22x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 24)
        Stb.TP23x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 25)
        Stb.TP24x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 26)
        Stb.TP25x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 27)
        Stb.TP26x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 28)
        Stb.TP27x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 29)
        Stb.TP28x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 30)
        Stb.TP29x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 31)
        Stb.tA.Caption = .Cells(i, c + 1)
        Stb.tB.Caption = .Cells(i + 1, c + 1)
        Stb.tC.Caption = .Cells(i + 2, c + 1)
        Stb.tD.Caption = .Cells(i + 3, c + 1)
        Stb.tE.Caption = .Cells(i + 4, c + 1)
        Stb.tF.Caption = .Cells(i + 5, c + 1)
        Stb.tG.Caption = .Cells(i + 6, c + 1)
        Stb.tH.Caption = .Cells(i + 7, c + 1)
        Stb.tI.Caption = .Cells(i + 8, c + 1)
        Stb.tJ.Caption = .Cells(i + 9, c + 1)
        Stb.tK.Caption = .Cells(i + 10, c + 1)
        Stb.tL.Caption = .Cells(i + 11, c + 1)
        Stb.tM.Caption = .Cells(i + 12, c + 1)
        Stb.tN.Caption = .Cells(i + 13, c + 1)
        Stb.teO.Caption = .Cells(i + 14, c + 1)
        Stb.tP.Caption = .Cells(i + 15, c + 1)
        Stb.tQ.Caption = .Cells(i + 16, c + 1)
        Stb.tR.Caption = .Cells(i + 17, c + 1)
        Stb.tS.Caption = .Cells(i + 18, c + 1)
        Stb.tT.Caption = .Cells(i + 19, c + 1)
        Stb.tU.Caption = .Cells(i + 20, c + 1)
        Stb.tV.Caption = .Cells(i + 21, c + 1)
        Stb.tW.Caption = .Cells(i + 22, c + 1)
        Stb.tX.Caption = .Cells(i + 23, c + 1)
        Stb.tY.Caption = .Cells(i + 24, c + 1)
        Stb.tZ.Caption = .Cells(i + 25, c + 1)
        'skip row 78
        Stb.oA.Caption = .Cells(i + 27, c + 1)
        Stb.oB.Caption = .Cells(i + 28, c + 1)
        Stb.oC.Caption = .Cells(i + 29, c + 1)
        Stb.oD.Caption = .Cells(i + 30, c + 1)
        Stb.oE.Caption = .Cells(i + 31, c + 1)
        Stb.oF.Caption = .Cells(i + 32, c + 1)
        Stb.oG.Caption = .Cells(i + 33, c + 1)
        Stb.oH.Caption = .Cells(i + 34, c + 1)
        Stb.oI.Caption = .Cells(i + 35, c + 1)
        Stb.Show
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Problem signature:**

```
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: EXCEL.EXE
  Application Version:  16.0.8431.2236
  Application Timestamp:    5a9aa882
  Fault Module Name:    unknown
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00000000
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    1033
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has a similar issue in the future, here's the answer I found that works...

Move all of the label caption code to a sub in the UserForm code (Right click userform name -> View code) under Private Sub UserForm_Initialize(), so the labels occur with the loading.

Then the Selection_Change code does the checks for the appropriate range and just loads the userForm.

---

SelectionChange:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Cells(918, 6).Value = "No" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim r As Long, t As Long
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    t = 0
    Select Case r
        Case 25 To 44 '1
            t = 24
        Case 115 To 134 '2
            t = 114
        Case 205 To 224 '3
            t = 204
        Case 295 To 314 '4
            t = 294
        Case 385 To 404 '5
            t = 384
        Case 475 To 494 '6
            t = 474
        Case 565 To 584 '7
            t = 564
        Case 655 To 674 '8
            t = 654
        Case 745 To 764 '9
            t = 744
        Case 835 To 854 '10
            t = 834
    End Select
    If t = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(t + 1, 3), Cells(t + 20, 3))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Stb.Show
End Sub
```

---

Initialize:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, t As Long
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    c = ActiveCell.Column
    Select Case r
        Case 25 To 44 '1
            i = 52
            t = 24
        Case 115 To 134 '2
            i = 142
            t = 114
        Case 205 To 224 '3
            i = 232
            t = 204
        Case 295 To 314 '4
            i = 322
            t = 294
        Case 385 To 404 '5
            i = 412
            t = 384
        Case 475 To 494 '6
            i = 502
            t = 474
        Case 565 To 584 '7
            i = 592
            t = 564
        Case 655 To 674 '8
            i = 682
            t = 654
        Case 745 To 764 '9
            i = 772
            t = 744
        Case 835 To 854 '10
            i = 862
            t = 834
    End Select
    With Sheets("Stability")
        Stb.Cond1.Caption = .Cells(r, c + 1)
        Stb.Cond2.Caption = .Cells(r, c + 1)
        Stb.TP01.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 3)
        Stb.TP02.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 4)
        Stb.TP03.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 5)
        Stb.TP04.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 6)
        Stb.TP05.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 7)
        Stb.TP06.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 8)
        Stb.TP07.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 9)
        Stb.TP08.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 10)
        Stb.TP09.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 11)
        Stb.TP10.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 12)
        Stb.TP11.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 13)
        Stb.TP12.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 14)
        Stb.TP13.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 15)
        Stb.TP14.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 16)
        Stb.TP15.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 17)
        Stb.TP16.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 18)
        Stb.TP17.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 19)
        Stb.TP18.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 20)
        Stb.TP19.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 21)
        Stb.TP20.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 22)
        Stb.TP21.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 23)
        Stb.TP22.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 24)
        Stb.TP23.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 25)
        Stb.TP24.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 26)
        Stb.TP25.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 27)
        Stb.TP26.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 28)
        Stb.TP27.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 29)
        Stb.TP28.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 30)
        Stb.TP29.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 31)
        Stb.TP01x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 3)
        Stb.TP02x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 4)
        Stb.TP03x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 5)
        Stb.TP04x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 6)
        Stb.TP05x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 7)
        Stb.TP06x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 8)
        Stb.TP07x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 9)
        Stb.TP08x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 10)
        Stb.TP09x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 11)
        Stb.TP10x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 12)
        Stb.TP11x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 13)
        Stb.TP12x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 14)
        Stb.TP13x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 15)
        Stb.TP14x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 16)
        Stb.TP15x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 17)
        Stb.TP16x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 18)
        Stb.TP17x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 19)
        Stb.TP18x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 20)
        Stb.TP19x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 21)
        Stb.TP20x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 22)
        Stb.TP21x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 23)
        Stb.TP22x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 24)
        Stb.TP23x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 25)
        Stb.TP24x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 26)
        Stb.TP25x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 27)
        Stb.TP26x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 28)
        Stb.TP27x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 29)
        Stb.TP28x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 30)
        Stb.TP29x.Caption = .Cells(t, c + 31)
        Stb.tA.Caption = .Cells(i, c + 1)
        Stb.tB.Caption = .Cells(i + 1, c + 1)
        Stb.tC.Caption = .Cells(i + 2, c + 1)
        Stb.tD.Caption = .Cells(i + 3, c + 1)
        Stb.tE.Caption = .Cells(i + 4, c + 1)
        Stb.tF.Caption = .Cells(i + 5, c + 1)
        Stb.tG.Caption = .Cells(i + 6, c + 1)
        Stb.tH.Caption = .Cells(i + 7, c + 1)
        Stb.tI.Caption = .Cells(i + 8, c + 1)
        Stb.tJ.Caption = .Cells(i + 9, c + 1)
        Stb.tK.Caption = .Cells(i + 10, c + 1)
        Stb.tL.Caption = .Cells(i + 11, c + 1)
        Stb.tM.Caption = .Cells(i + 12, c + 1)
        Stb.tN.Caption = .Cells(i + 13, c + 1)
        Stb.teO.Caption = .Cells(i + 14, c + 1)
        Stb.tP.Caption = .Cells(i + 15, c + 1)
        Stb.tQ.Caption = .Cells(i + 16, c + 1)
        Stb.tR.Caption = .Cells(i + 17, c + 1)
        Stb.tS.Caption = .Cells(i + 18, c + 1)
        Stb.tT.Caption = .Cells(i + 19, c + 1)
        Stb.tU.Caption = .Cells(i + 20, c + 1)
        Stb.tV.Caption = .Cells(i + 21, c + 1)
        Stb.tW.Caption = .Cells(i + 22, c + 1)
        Stb.tX.Caption = .Cells(i + 23, c + 1)
        Stb.tY.Caption = .Cells(i + 24, c + 1)
        Stb.tZ.Caption = .Cells(i + 25, c + 1)
        'skip row 78
        Stb.oA.Caption = .Cells(i + 27, c + 1)
        Stb.oB.Caption = .Cells(i + 28, c + 1)
        Stb.oC.Caption = .Cells(i + 29, c + 1)
        Stb.oD.Caption = .Cells(i + 30, c + 1)
        Stb.oE.Caption = .Cells(i + 31, c + 1)
        Stb.oF.Caption = .Cells(i + 32, c + 1)
        Stb.oG.Caption = .Cells(i + 33, c + 1)
        Stb.oH.Caption = .Cells(i + 34, c + 1)
        Stb.oI.Caption = .Cells(i + 35, c + 1)
    End With
End Sub
```